# Nginx proxy_pass not working correctly

Tags: nginx, google-oauth

I am deploying my `Flask` application on `Ubuntu` using `Nginx`, i've also installed **letsencrypt** service so i can use **https** with google oauth api , i also added my **callback** uri's IP and Domain in my **Authorized redirect URIs** inside my google console.

My problem is if i want to login using google oauth, i get redirected to **http://127.0.0.1:5445/login/google/authorized?state=** and get this error:

`This site can’t be reached`

This error i get after google redirect me to my website, but i don't know why it redirects me to this ip address i am redirecting it to the original website in my nginx config as you can see here `proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:5445/login/google/authorized https://www.website.com/login/google/authorized;`

**app.conf**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com www.website.com *.website.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5445/;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:5445/login/google/authorized https://www.website.com/login/google/authorized;
        #include uwsgi_params;
        #uwsgi_pass unix:/home/userp/website.com/website.com.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    #ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM$
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;


    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}
```

**app.service**:

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve website.com"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid userp
setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/userp/website.com/venv/bin
chdir /home/userp/website.com
exec uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5445 --protocol=https -w manage:app
```

Comment: any help guys !!

Comment: any suggestions guys please !!